# material-table third state to sort column

Tags: reactjs, sorting, material-table

Using the [material-table](https://material-table.com/) react component, I saw a strange behaviour on sorting a column.

Clicking a column 3 times removes the sort. You can try to sort the column `name` on [this example](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/sorting).

Is there a way to remove 3 states (ascending, descending and back to the original state) behaviour and have only 2 (ascending, descending) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a bug, but it's the intended behaviour. It has added in material-table component and the story is described [here](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/985)

In order to disable this behaviour and have only 2 states, you have to disable `thirdSortClick`

```
 <Table
   options={{
     thirdSortClick: false
   }}
   title=...
   data=...
/>
```